# Why isn't nginx handling requests in this docker-compose/django setup?

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to learn docker and docker-compose, and have run into a roadblock.

The stack is a python:2.7 base image serving up django pages, and this part works fine. I now want to put nginx in front of it as a reverse proxy. When I access localhost:8000 I get django pages as expected. When I load up localhost with no port, I get nothing ("Problem loading page"). I assume the connection between django container's port 8080 and nginx port 80 isn't happening, and I'm so new to docker that it's probably something simple that I'm not seeing.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: ./app/
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    volumes_from:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web

  # probably not relevant to my issue
  db:
    image: postgres
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6380:6380"
    volumes:
      - ./redisdata/:/data
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /code/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The nginx service starts successfully and appears to be running. I checked it's log using

```
docker-compose logs nginx
```

And it was empty.

Comment: In your nginx config, try this:  `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` instead of  `proxy_pass http://web:8000;`

Comment: Did you try to access the nginx served page then go to log ? Or did you try to saw the log before going to the page ?

Comment: Did you actually include the nginx config file in ./nginx/Dockerfile?